# Sorting data by time column python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have this dataset which is formatted in the way:

```
   time_col            val_col  value            
0   2021-04-28 12:10:00 10       Students   
1   2021-04-28 12:20:00 20       Students
2   2021-04-28 12:30:00 20       Students
3   2021-04-28 12:40:00 35       Students
4   2021-04-28 12:50:00 35       Students
5   2021-04-28 12:10:00 100      Noise
6   2021-04-28 12:20:00 130      Noise
7   2021-04-28 12:30:00 155      Noise
8   2021-04-28 12:40:00 160      Noise
9   2021-04-28 12:50:00 175      Noise
```

The times are duplicated so I would want the output to look like:

```
   time_col            Students  Noise            
0   2021-04-28 12:10:00 10       100    
1   2021-04-28 12:20:00 20       130
2   2021-04-28 12:30:00 20       155
3   2021-04-28 12:40:00 35       160
4   2021-04-28 12:50:00 35       175
```

Please could you let me know how to do this.

Here is how I produced the first df:

```
time_col = [np.datetime64('2021-04-28T12:10:00'), np.datetime64('2021-04-28T12:20:00'), np.datetime64('2021-04-28T12:30:00'), np.datetime64('2021-04-28T12:40:00'), np.datetime64('2021-04-28T12:50:00'),
           np.datetime64('2021-04-28T12:10:00'), np.datetime64('2021-04-28T12:30:00'), np.datetime64('2021-04-28T12:30:00'), np.datetime64('2021-04-28T12:40:00'), np.datetime64('2021-04-28T12:50:00')]
val_col = [10,20,20,35,35, 100,135,155,160,175]
value = ["Students", "Students", "Students", "Students", "Students", "Noise", "Noise", "Noise", "Noise", "Noise"]
df_1 = pd.DataFrame([time_col, val_col, value])
df_2 = pd.DataFrame.transpose(df_1)
df_2.columns = ["time_col", "val_col", "value"]
```

As you can see I am new to python and I am aware that is not the best way of creating the df

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot):

```
# make the val_col values floats instead of objects
df_2.val_col = df_2.val_col.astype(float)

# pivot the df and aggregate duplicate indeces with the mean function
df_2.pivot_table(columns="value", values="val_col", index="time_col")
```

Resuting DataFrame:

```
value                Noise  Students
time_col                            
2021-04-28 12:10:00  100.0      10.0
2021-04-28 12:20:00    NaN      20.0
2021-04-28 12:30:00  145.0      20.0
2021-04-28 12:40:00  160.0      35.0
2021-04-28 12:50:00  175.0      35.0
```

You can pass an `aggfunc` to `pivot_table`, (e.g. `mean`) to deal with multiple measurements for the same time slot.